# Overload method? Why won't this function work?

Tags: c#

```
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int id = 0, stock = 0, published = 0, newstock;
            double price = 0.00;
            string type = " ", title = " ", author = " ";

            Program inventroy = new Program();
            inventroy.read_one_record(ref id, ref stock, ref published, ref price, ref type, ref title, ref author);

            Console.WriteLine("Update Number In Stock");
            Console.WriteLine("=======================");
            Console.Write("Item ID: ");
            Console.WriteLine(id);
            Console.Write("Item Type: ");
            Console.WriteLine(type);
            Console.Write("Price: ");
            Console.WriteLine(price);
            Console.Write("Number In Stock: ");
            Console.WriteLine(stock);
            Console.Write("Title: ");
            Console.WriteLine(title);
            Console.Write("Author/Artist: ");
            Console.WriteLine(author);
            Console.Write("Published: ");
            Console.WriteLine(published);
            Console.WriteLine("=======================");

            Console.Write("Please Enter New Stock Number: ");
            string line = Console.ReadLine();
            newstock = int.Parse(line);

            Program writeinv = new Program();

            writeinv.write_one_record(ref id, ref newstock, ref published, ref price, ref type, ref title, ref author);
        }

        void read_one_record(ref int id, ref int stock, ref int published, ref double price, ref string type, ref string title, ref string author)
        {
            StreamReader myFile = File.OpenText("Inventory.dat");

            id = int.Parse(myFile.ReadLine());
            stock = int.Parse(myFile.ReadLine());
            published = int.Parse(myFile.ReadLine());
            price = double.Parse(myFile.ReadLine());
            type = myFile.ReadLine();
            title = myFile.ReadLine();
            author = myFile.ReadLine();

            myFile.Close();

        }
        void write_one_record(int id, int newstock, int published, double price, string type, string title, string author)
        {
            StreamWriter myFile = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite("Inventory.dat"));


            myFile.WriteLine(id);
            myFile.WriteLine(newstock);
            myFile.WriteLine(published);
            myFile.WriteLine(price);
            myFile.WriteLine(type);
            myFile.WriteLine(title);
            myFile.WriteLine(author);

            myFile.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone compile this (or just paste code into compiler) and tell me why writeinv.write_one_record(ref id, ref newstock, ref published, ref price, ref type, ref title, ref author); says it has invalid arguments?

"The best overloaded method match for 'as2.programs.write_one_record(int, int, int, double, string, string, string)' has some invalid arguments.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Reduce your code example, please. (That is, remove **everything** except what's necessary to make the error appear.)

Comment: you need void write_one_record(ref int id, ref int newstock , ....

Comment: why are you passing your arguments with the ref modifier?

Comment: Because I don't want to pass them with value? lol... if I need void in front why didn't It prompt an error for the read ?

Comment: @Nogg They should probably be `out` parameters in this case. Better yet, `read_one_record` should return an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define write_one_record as

```
void write_one_record(int id, int newstock, int published, double price, string type, string title, string author)
```

-> No `ref` parameters

but you call it as

```
writeinv.write_one_record(ref id, ref newstock, ref published, ref price, ref type, ref title, ref author);
```

-> all `ref` parameters

Comment: Thank you. This was explained well and I don't know how I missed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`write_one_record` doesn't contain any `ref` parameters yet in your call to it they all do...

Given the way your method uses the parameters it should be called with:

```
writeinv.write_one_record(id, newstock, published, price, type, title, author);
```

Rather than:

```
writeinv.write_one_record(ref id, ref newstock, ref published, ref price, ref type, ref title, ref author);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read the [ref (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) first .

you need add the ref keyword also to your method parameter

```
write_one_record(ref int id, ref int newstock , ....
```

Answer (score 0):

**You're missing the** `ref` **keyword in each of the arguments**

If you're trying to use the `ref` `keyword` when calling `write_one_record(...)` you need it in the method declaration as well. Just like in you did in `void red_one_record(...)`

```
void write_one_record(ref int id, ref int newstock, ref int published, ref double price, ref string type, ref string title, ref string author)
```

If you didn't intend to use `ref`, remove it from the call of the method.

Comment: Where are you talking about? I have read and write both exactly the same.

Comment: No you don't, you're not including the `ref` in the method declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Because `write_one_record` parameters are not declared as "ref", yet you are passing them as "ref".

Answer (score 0):

Either don't use ref or directly add "ref" before each parameter that you use when you call your method.